# VSCode removing React from imports on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

after switching to vscode 1.68.1

every time on saving the file its automatically removing the React from the import
at first i though this could be an eslint issue as i am using eslint for formatting but after removing eslint plugin issue remains the same

here is my settings.json

```json
{
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.eol": "\r\n",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
        "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off",
    "prettier.enable": false,
    "eslint.format.enable": false,
   
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "aeschli.vscode-css-formatter"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    }
}
```

and here is the .eslintrc

```json
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react", "react-hooks"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "max-len": ["error", { "code": 220 }]
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
          "node": {
            "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
          }
        }
      }
};
```

Comment: can you post your tsconfig file?

Comment: @tHeSiD i am not using typescript and i can not find any tsconfig in the project also

Comment: do you have an `.eslintrc` or `eslint.config.json` file ?

Comment: yes @tHeSiD
updated ans with that

Comment: I got the exact same issue on windows and mac.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding these rules in **eslintrc**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 0,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0
  }
}
```

OR

Try adding **"jsx": "react"** to your **jsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This helps VS-Code understand that **React** is implicitly referenced by the jsx elements in your file.

I had the same problem in multiple projects, after adding these rules, solves the problem for me.

Comment: In my project the rules were in package.json inside "eslintConfig": {}.
Thx a lot @Mudassar

Answer (score 1):

VS Code expects that every project declares a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions) or [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) and if none is provided, it defaults it to

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

This effectively means that if you have React imports in your code, they will be preserved.

To adopt the latest react 17+ standard with the [`_jsx`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) transform, the environment type needs to be `react-jsx`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

Comment: in my case, I added `"jsx": "react-native",` instead since my project is React Native. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "on",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "on"
  }
}
```

Add these rules to your eslint config

Comment: unfortunately no success even after adding those rules

Comment: FYI ... Configuration for rule "react/jsx-uses-react" is invalid: Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"on"').

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `"source.organizeImports": true` line from your settings, or setting it to `false`.

I think VS Code thinks the `React` import is unnecessary because its only used implicitly (which can be a problem if your compiler requires an explicit import to bundle correctly).

Answer (score 0):

add type on your tsx file, to prevent removed automatically by vscode

```js
import React from 'react';
type _react = typeof React
```

.eslint

```js
{
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 0, // ignore validation must include react scope in jsx/tsx
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0, // ignore validation must include react scope in jsx/tsx
    'no-unused-vars': 'off', // disable default eslint unused variable
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [ // ignore validation variable with prefix _
      'warn',
      {
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
        varsIgnorePattern: '^_',
        caughtErrorsIgnorePattern: '^_'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was to comment this out:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    // "source.organizeImports": true,
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem, when removing the extensions I found it was vscode, downgrading to version 1.67.2 solved it

Comment: downgrading is not a proper solution imo